# Can app name for iOS Search be different than CFBundleDisplayName?

Tags: ios, xcode, cfbundledisplayname

I have an app called "French Translator +" in the app store.

There is not enough space below the app icon to display the entire name so I set CFBundleDisplayName = "Translator +".

However, when I type "French" in iOS Search, my app doesn't appear in the results of the section for APPLICATIONS.

How can I get iOS Search to index "French Translator +" while displaying "Translator +" below the app icon?

[image]

Comment: See the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799748/specify-spotlight-keywords-ios-9

Comment: The Core Spotlight Framework indexes data inside the app, such as an entry for "voiture" in a French dictionary. It doesn't appear to allow adding terms to the search index for the app title, as described above.

Comment: I see that you actually asked this question a couple of months ago at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343980/how-can-i-choose-a-different-ios-app-name-for-spotlight, *and* the person who answered that time gave you almost exactly the same answer that I gave you today. Is there something wrong with these answers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I choose a different iOS app name for Spotlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343980/how-can-i-choose-a-different-ios-app-name-for-spotlight)

Answer (score 0):

The question *is* already answered in [Specify Spotlight keywords iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799748/specify-spotlight-keywords-ios-9)

As you point out, Core Spotlight indexes data in the app. Data that *you* provide. So all you need to do is provide it with some data so Spotlight Search can find your app.

Adding this to `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` worked for me:

```
let attributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: "application")
attributeSet.title = "French Translator"
attributeSet.keywords = ["french", "translation", "translator"]
attributeSet.contentDescription = "French Language Translation App"

let item = CSSearchableItem(uniqueIdentifier: "5C0B7719-3BE7-4441-892D-A786AA431BDD", domainIdentifier: nil, attributeSet: attributeSet)
CSSearchableIndex.default().indexSearchableItems([item]) {
  print("Finished indexing with \(String(describing: $0))")
}
```

Comment: This is correct for the data. But, the result shows way below and not in the applications section.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `title` and `keywords` are invalid at some point.
And this works for me.

```
        let attributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(contentType: .text)
        attributeSet.displayName = "Name"
        attributeSet.contentDescription = "Descruption"
        attributeSet.artist = "Lucas"

        let searchableItem = CSSearchableItem(uniqueIdentifier: "starWar", domainIdentifier: "com.fatbobman.Movies.Sci-fi", attributeSet: attributeSet)

        CSSearchableIndex.default().indexSearchableItems([searchableItem]){ error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```